# What is the correct way of moving home?

Tags: mount, partition, rm, home

I am trying to move /home onto a dedicated partition.

What I already did:

- created the partition
- created a filesystem
- mounted the partition into a temporary folder
- rsynched all files into the temporary folder

Until here everything was self-explaining.

Now the next step would be to mount the new parition into `/home` which works just fine, even live, I also added the `/etc/fstab` entry.

**My question now is:
How can I delete the old (original) `/home` folder?**

Since `/home` is now pointing to my new partition, I tried to mount the original drive into another space like `/tmp/origin` and delete the old `/home` there, but the result is always the same:

```
mkdir /tmp/original
sudo mount -o rw /dev/sda1 /tmp/original
sudo rm -r /tmp/original/home/
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/original/home/': Device or resource busy
```

`ls -la` only shows an empty directory:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 25 01:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Aug 25 00:34 ../
```

Comment: You cannot delete a mount point. Your files have most likely been deleted.

Comment: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: @oldfred sure thing, but thanks for reminding!